# Database for personal income/expense, property and small business management

Tags: database-design, schema

I am currently working on a personal finance management project. In my project a person want to manage his personal income, expense. Beside this, he has land business. He buy and sell lands. and some micro business.

main tables are

```
--Accounts (Bank, Bank2, Cash in Hand)
--Parties (who paid or whome to pay)
--Catagory (Salary, Entertainment)
--Payment Method (Cash,)
--Assets (Property)
--Loan (Client may take loan or give someone loan)
--Business (some other business like, accessories, sharemarket)
```

So finally i made this Schema for this, but i'm not sure this will work or not. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[image]